# conditional scatter in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to scatter in matlab (2D) where the color of the marker is conditioned on a third column. I can use loops and hold on but maybe there is a simpler way.

Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fourth argument to scatter allows you to specify a colour. From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html):

> scatter(X,Y,S,C)
>
> ...
>
> C determines the color of each marker. When C is a vector the same length as X and Y, the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors in the current colormap. When C is a 1-by-3 matrix, it specifies the colors of the markers as RGB values. If you have 3 points in the scatter plot and wish to have the colors be indices into the colormap, C should be a 3-by-1 matrix. C can also be a color string (see ColorSpec for a list of color string specifiers).

Try something like:

```
X = rand(1, 10);
Y = rand(1, 10);
colour = randi(3, 1, 10)

colour =

 2     1     3     1     3     1     2     2     3     1

scatter(X, Y, [], colour, 'filled');
```

[image]

If your datasets are large, and there are few different colour categories, I tend to find that using [plot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) with hold on is a faster way to plot.

Answer (score 2):

@Bill's answer is fine, but if you have access to Statistics Toolbox you could also try `gscatter`.